# Vue components not rendering when using Nav bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having issues implementing a nav bar to my website.

When I try to use router-view in App.vue, my components (such as Signup) do not render and instead show a blank page (along with the navbar). It should be showing my signup form. However, it does take me to the correct link (http://localhost:8080/signup). I get the same issue when I click on the link 'Home'. Despite placing some dummy text in the template, I do not see it rendered on my page.

I am successfully able to render components correctly when I import the components directly in the template of App.vue. However, when I attempt to use router-view instead, the components do not render. From my understanding, router-view acts as a placeholder and should render components when they are clicked.

Here is the relevant code from my project:

Router > index.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import HomePage from '@/components/HomePage.vue';
import UserSignup from '@/components/UserSignup.vue';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HomePage',
      component: HomePage
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      name: 'UserSignup',
      component: UserSignup
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavBar />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { NavBar },
}
</script>
```

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

UserSignup.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="signup-container">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" v-model="username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" v-model="password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    name: 'UserSignup',
    data() {
      return {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleSubmit() {
        const userData = {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        };
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/', userData)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped> 
/* Some styling */
</style>
```

components > NavBar.vue:

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
      <router-link to="/signup">Signup</router-link>
      <span class="inactive-link">Login</span> <!-- Not clickable for now -->
    </nav>
</template>
  
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'NavBar'
    };
</script>

<style scoped> 
/* Some styling */
</style>
```

[image: Lastly, here is a screenshot of everything inside my src folder]

I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I don't see something wrong about your code, what version of vue-router are you using ? You should have vue-router in v4 with vue3.
Also why do you have <div id="app"> in your App.vue, you would have already this id in your index.html.

Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: My version of vue-router is 4.2.5 and vue version 3.4.13.

I have 1 console warning but I believe it's unrelated.

"Feature flag __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__ is not explicitly defined. You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue, which expects these compile-time feature flags to be globally injected via the bundler config in order to get better tree-shaking in the production bundle.

For more details, see https://link.vuejs.org/feature-flags."

The div in App.vue is necessary as without it the application breaks. It serves as the root container for my app.

Comment: they meant the `id="app"` part of the div is unnecessary since index.html should already have a div with that id which your entire app mounts to.  It's a moot issue since Vue can function just fine either way.  However, it's true that there is nothing wrong with the code provided so far.  I made a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-wqkn7l?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev) using your code and it works perfectly fine.  There must be something else not shown causing your issue. Maybe you can provide a repo or other runnable reproduction?

Comment: I've uploaded the repo here: https://github.com/Mujahidul46/Habitville
Hopefully that can help as from what you're saying, it seems the code I provided is fine

Comment: you installed vue-router in the wrong directory.  See your top-level [package.json](https://github.com/Mujahidul46/Habitville/blob/main/package.json) here where vue-router is installed and nothing else.  It should be installed in your frontend project [package.json](https://github.com/Mujahidul46/Habitville/blob/main/habitville_frontend/package.json)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the issue. Once I installed vue-router in frontend directory, it was fixed.